# i need to filter or remove some lines from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

This is the input file, it is already properly structured:

```
Name:  mr. Apple
class:  class 1
sub:  subject 1
ContactNo: 11111
Name:  mr. ball
class:  class  2
sub:  subject  2
ContactNo: 2222
Name:  mr. cat
class:  class 3
sub:  subject 3
ContactNo: 33333
class:  class 4
sub:  subject 4
ContactNo:44444
class:  class 5
sub:  subject 5
ContactNo: 55555
Name:  mr. tom
class:  class 9
sub:  subject 9
ContactNo: 99999
```

As you can see there are some details without the names.

> > for example:
> >      class:  class 4
> >      sub:  subject 4
> >      ContactNo:44444

I need to remove these and keep only the the details of those with names.

Expected output:

```
Name:  mr. Apple
class:  class 1
sub:  subject 1
ContactNo: 11111
Name:  mr. ball
class:  class  2
sub:  subject  2
ContactNo: 2222
Name:  mr. cat
class:  class 3
sub:  subject 3
ContactNo: 33333
Name:  mr. tom
class:  class 9
sub:  subject 9
ContactNo: 99999
```

I've tried this :

```py
errors = []                       # The list where we will store results.
linenum = 0
substr = "Name:".lower()          # Substring to search for.
substr1 = "class:".lower()
substr2 = "sub:".lower()
substr3 = "ContactNo:".lower()

with open ('scrap.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        linenum += 1
        if line.lower().find(substr) != -1:    # if case-insensitive match,
            errors.append(line)
        elif  line.lower().find(substr1) != -1:        
            errors.append(line)
        elif  line.lower().find(substr2) != -1:     
            errors.append(line)
        elif  line.lower().find(substr3) != -1:      
            errors.append(line)

for err in errors:
    fp = open("rawextract.txt","a")
    fp.write(err)
    fp.close()
    print(err)
```

But i've no idea how to discard the incomplete lines.

Comment: is the order of Name, Class, Sub, ContactNo guaranteed or could there be Name,SubC,Name,ContanctNo, ... parts as well?

Comment: @PatrickArtner the order is always same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with a regex pattern that matches the properly structured sequence of expected headers:

```
import re
with open('scrap.txt') as myfile:
    for m in re.findall('Name:.*\nclass:.*\nsub:.*\nContactNo:.*', myfile.read()):
        print(m)
```

This outputs:

```
Name:  mr. Apple
class:  class 1
sub:  subject 1
ContactNo: 11111
Name:  mr. ball
class:  class  2
sub:  subject  2
ContactNo: 2222
Name:  mr. cat
class:  class 3
sub:  subject 3
ContactNo: 33333
Name:  mr. tom
class:  class 9
sub:  subject 9
ContactNo: 99999
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an endless iterable of

```
['name:', 'class:', 'sub:', 'concatno:', 'name:', 'class:', ...]
```

using [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

Then you check if the line contains the next value, if so write it to results, else skip it:

**Create data file:**

```
with open("f.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""
Name:  mr. Apple
class:  class 1
sub:  subject 1
ContactNo: 11111
Name:  mr. ball
class:  class  2
sub:  subject  2
ContactNo: 2222
Name:  mr. cat
class:  class 3
sub:  subject 3
ContactNo: 33333
Name:  mr. tom
class:  class 9
sub:  subject 9
ContactNo: 99999
""")
```

**Program:**

```
from itertools import cycle
order = ["name:","class:","sub:","contactno:"]
t = cycle(order)

nxt = next(t) # name: 
with open("f.txt") as f, open("mod.txt","w") as writer:
    for line in f:
        if nxt in line.lower():
            writer.write(line)
            nxt = next(t)       # advance to the next thing to be read

print(open("mod.txt").read())
```

Output:

```
Name:  mr. Apple
class:  class 1
sub:  subject 1
ContactNo: 11111
Name:  mr. ball
class:  class  2
sub:  subject  2
ContactNo: 2222
Name:  mr. cat
class:  class 3
sub:  subject 3
ContactNo: 33333
Name:  mr. tom
class:  class 9
sub:  subject 9
ContactNo: 99999
```

This will fail if your valid data skips part of what should be in it:

```
Name:  mr. tom    # taken
class:  class 9   # taken
sub:  subject 9   # taken, no contact number follows
Name:  mr. tom    # skipped
class:  class 9   # skipped
sub:  subject 9   # skipped
ContactNo: 0000   # then this will be taken
```

---

You can make it slighty more robust by using:

```
with open("f.txt") as f, open("mod.txt","w") as writer:
    for line in f:
        if nxt in line.lower():
            writer.write(line)
            nxt = next(t)       # advance to the next thing to be read
        elif starter in line.lower():
            print("Incomplete set - beginning next one")
            while True:
                nxt = next(t)
                if nxt == starter:
                    break
                nxt = next(t)
                writer.write(line)
```

Which would, in case of incomplete data and now standing on a new `Name: ...` line  start over and not miss it...